# What medals can be earned in Warzone?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In Star Wars: The Old Republic, completing certain objectives while in a Warzone will earn you a "medal" buff, which gives you additional valor and commendations when the Warzone ends.

What is the criteria for each medal? Is it possible to earn certain medals more than once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know the complete list but here is what I at least do know. I'm not sure if the complete list has been achieved yet either way.

- Soldier - 25 kills
- Assassin - 1 solo kill
- Combatant - 90k dmg
- ??? - 360k dmg
- Commando - 10 kills
- Quick Draw - 1 killing blow
- Shield - 5k Defended
- Guardian - 2k Defense 1 life
- Defender - 1k Defender points
- Paladin -  10k defense 1 life
- Demolisher - 3k+ single hit
- Annihilator - 6k+ single hit
- Healer - 90k Healing
- ??? - 360k Healing
- Medic - 3k+ single heal
- ??? - 6k+ single heal

There are also some for getting defender points but I cannot recall the amounts for them or their names.

I do know however that you cannot get duplicates for any of these, as I've personally healed 20+ games and I've done almost every heal at 2.5k+ and never got more than one medal for it.

Hope this helps, I'd love to see the full complete list aswell ! ... if anyone has any to add or update, comment and I'll add it to the list here so we can have something for it in one place.

Comment: Thanks! For completeness: do you know which ones are bronze, silver, or gold?

Comment: off top of my head I don't, but I will make note of this as I go. Good idea !

Comment: @Sjoerd - I think that's based on how many you have, not what they are.

Comment: @Ward Could you update this to include the new medals found in Patch 1.2?

Answer (score 5):

- Trauma Surgeon – 5k healing from a single heal
- Destroyer – Dealing 300K damage
- Savior – Healing 300K
- Warden – Earning 3k Defender Points
- Protector – 50K Protection
- The Gold ranking is awarded for earning 6 or more medals during a match
- The Silver ranking is awarded for 3-5 medals
- The Bronze ranking is awarded for 1-2 medals

Answer (score 5):

These are all the medals updated from 3.0.

When you get 8 medals in 1 life you are `Unbeatable`

When you get 14 medals in 1 life you are `Invincible`

When you get 18 medals in 1 life you are `Immortal`

**Bronze, Silver or Gold:**

- Bronze 1-7 medals earned in 1 game
- Silver 8-13 medals earned in 1 game
- Gold 14 or more medals earned in 1 game

**Available medals**

- Quick Draw - 1 Killing Blow
- Assassin - 1 solo kill
- Soldier - 4 Kills
- Commando - 8 Kills
- Combatant - 90k Damage Dealt
- Destroyer - 360k Damage Dealt
- Demolisher - 3k Damage Single Hit
- Annihilator - 6k Damage Single Hit
- Shield - 6k Defense
- Guardian - 2.4k Defense in 1 life
- Paladin - 12k Defense in 1 life
- Protector - 150K defense
- Healer - 150K Healed
- Savior - 650K Healed
- Medic - 3k Single Heal
- Trauma Surgeon - 6k Single Heal
- Offense Basic - 1 Attacker Point
- Offense Bronze - 3K Attacker Points
- Offense Silver - 5K Attacker Points
- Offense Gold - 7.5k Attacker Points
- Offense Platinum - 10K Attacker Points
- Offense Diamond - 15K Attacker Points
- Defense Basic = 1 Defender Point
- Defense Bronze - 3K Defender Points
- Defense Silver - 5K Defender Points
- Defense Gold - 7.5k Defender Points
- Defense Platinum - 10K Defender Points
- Defense Diamond - 15K Defender Points
- Reinforcer - You joined the match after it started
- Dauntless VI - 5 Minute Victory / 3 Minute Download
- Dauntless V - 6 Minute Victory / 3:30 Minute Download
- Dauntless IV - 7 Minute Victory / 4 Minute Download
- Dauntless III - 8 Minute Victory / 4:30 Minute Download
- Dauntless II - 9 Minute Victory / 5 Minute Download
- Dauntless I - 10 Minute Victory / 5:30 Minute Download

**4v4 only**

- First blood in round 1
- First blood in round 2
- First blood in round 3
- Winning Round 1
- Winning Round 2
- Winning Round 3
- Survived a Round
- Swiftness round 1 - Winning round 1 in 1 minute
- Swiftness round 2 - Winning round 2 in 1 minute
- Swiftness round 3 - Winning round 3 in 1 minute
- Champion - Being victorious in an Arena

(Will be updated in future patches/ as soon as I know more names)